# Notify all Webrole instnance in windows azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm developing a cloud application, that indexing a large number of documents (with lucene), and hosting a wcf service to search it. I have 3 roles:

- I web role, which is hosting the WCF service, and keep a copy of the
  index in memory.
- I web role for administration (update the index).
- A worker role, which waiting for an update message, and if it's received starts the update.

I'm planning to have more instances of the WCF hosting web-role. 
What would be the best way, to notify all instance of the wcf role, to refresh their in-memonry index?

I would like to update the index once or twice a week, so the pull model (i think) would not be the best for me, because most of the "pulls" would be return with no results, and we have to pay for every storage transaction.

what you think?

Thanks for your answare.

T

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into Azure Service Bus Topics.  They allow notifications to be sent to more than one client.  You would still have to poll for messages every X minutes, but since the Service Bus is priced by message (penny per 10,000 messages) and you would only send messages twice a week, the cost will be insignificant.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/

Comment: actually, service bus is priced by request (its a message too).
Practically i have to pay for ever Client.Receive().

According to this:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh667438.aspx#BKMK_SBv2FAQ2_2

"This includes delivery of “null” messages in response to receive requests against empty queues/subscriptions"

Comment: You're right, but if you request messages once per minute, it's only 43k of messages per month per instance or about 0.5cents per server per month.  Is this really that expensive?

Comment: To clarify a bit: you pay a penny per 10,000 messages sent or received, not per 100,000. And if you have multiple subscribers, then you're actually writing one message per subscriber. That said: It's still about 2 orders of magnitude cheaper than a single role instance. And you can likely combine your role instances to save a whole lot more money than the cost of service bus messages.